# How to insert element at beginning of vector

Tags: c++, vector, insert

```
vector<int>grid = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 5, 3, 3, 6, 2, 6, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 6, 2, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 4, 7, 7, 8, 5, 8, 8, 8, 4, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8 };
const size_t gridSize = end(grid) - begin(grid);
int maxColour = *max_element(begin(grid), end(grid));

vector<vector<int>> colourPos(maxColour+1);

for (size_t i = 1; i < gridSize; ++i)
    colourPos[grid[i]].push_back(i);

for (size_t i = 0; i < colourPos.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << (i + 1) << ": ";
    for (int p : colourPos[i])
        std::cout << p << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

How can I insert an element at `colourPos[1][0]` so that it shifts all elements, and also to the other vectors within the `colourPos` vector?

e.g `[2][0]`, `[3][0]`.

I tried

```
colourPos[1][0].insert(0);
```

and just got "expression must have class type"

Comment: DR; TL; This is trivial look for `std::vector::insert`

Comment: @40two I tried that, I don't understand how to use it properly.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to insert a completely new vector at `colourPos[1]`?  Have you tried `colourPos.insert(colourPos.begin() + 1, vector<int>())`?

Comment: To insert at beginning of a `std::vector` (e.g., `v`) just `v.insert(v.begin(), val);`

Comment: @40two Doesn't work, I get "no instance of overload function..." It's a vector<vector

Comment: @cdhowie No I want to add an element at the start of each vector within the main vector

Comment: You'll need a loop to do this. `for(int i(0); i < colourPos.size(); ++i) {colourPos[i].insert(colourPos[i].begin(), 0); }`

Comment: @mrmike Ah, I see.  I misread.  In that case then using Mike Seymour's answer will work, just replace his `1` with a loop iteration variable.

Comment: If you're inserting at the front very often (at all) you probably want to use `deque` instead of `vector`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) takes an iterator to indicate where to insert. To insert at the beginning of `colourPos[1]`:

```
colourPos[1].insert(colourPos[1].begin(), 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

This insertion works:

```
vector<int> &cp1 = colourPos[1]; // & means reference to the subarray
cp1.insert(cp1.begin(), 2);      // insertion
```